# How can i use setstate without Re-render of component in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
constructor(props, context) {
super(props);
this.state = {
ShowVoucher: false
 }
```

I want to change state of **showVoucher**. without Re-Render of component. i have tried like this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
if(prevState.showVoucher!= this.state.showVoucher){
  this.setState({ ShowVoucher: false})
}
  }
```

But my code stucks in **infinite loop**. How can i solve it?
Any other solutions are welcome.

Comment: You cannot call setState inside `componentDidUpdate` to prevent from memory leak

Comment: why would you? but you could set another state(auxiliar) and when you want it to re-render set showVoucher state

Comment: why would you want to change the state if you don't want to re-render the component? Just stick it in a variable then.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store a value but not have the component re-render when that value changes, it shouldn't be in the state. It should be just an instance variable, e.g.

```
constructor(props, context) {
    this.ShowVoucher = false;
}
```

and then

```
this.ShowVoucher = true;
```

Do not put things in state then try to stop their changing from causing a re-render. That's an anti-pattern.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but "shouldComponentUpdate" exists precisely for this reason--there are perfectly acceptable things to keep in state that might not require an update. But this is a perfectly acceptable solution--the downvote confuses me.

Comment: @DaveNewton well if you NEVER want a re-render from changing certain values, then there's no point in having them in state. However, maybe you only want changing them not to cause a re-render in *certain* situations, in which case a `shouldComponentUpdate` solution would be appropriate. I just gave this answer based on the question, which has no other context.

Comment: That's why I said it's a perfectly acceptable solution. As you said, without context, it's impossible to know if it makes any sense.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe what you are looking for is shouldComponentUpdate
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if(this.state.showVoucher!==nextState.showVoucher){
   this.setState({ ShowVoucher: false})
   return false;
  } else return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but using this method just to prevent UI updates, as this answer is suggesting, is [officially discouraged](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: @RobinZigmond That's its *only* purpose. "Discouraged" means "if you think you need this performance optimization, this is where you put it". I might not use it for this usecase, but it's also not a huge deal.

Comment: The question is totally wrong from the title to details, and I don't know why guys rushed to answer. it is obvious that `if` condition is always `true` and none asked for more of the code and if there is another part that changes the state. otherwise why it get stuck in infnite loop of setSTate ? also the PO does not care about all these comments and answers :D